# AWS REST API - SignatureDoesNotMatch The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided

Tags: rest, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am getting SignatureDoesNotMatch error(The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method) while making "GET" request, only when making GET request with Query parameter using V4 signature. 
But with V2 signature everything works fine.
Without query parameter I am able to make GET(downloading files from S3), HEAD and PUT request using V4 and V2 signature.

I have used the samples AmazonS3SigV4_Samples_CSharp from AWS. Now I am trying to list objects from a bucket using REST API (Giving prefix as blank, listing only from root)

Here is my code snippet

```
var endpointUri = "http://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com:80/mytestbucket/?delimiter=%2f&prefix";
var uri = new Uri(endpointUri);

// for a simple GET, we have no body so supply the precomputed 'empty' hash
var headers = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
{AWS4SignerBase.X_Amz_Content_SHA256, AWS4SignerBase.EMPTY_BODY_SHA256},
{"content-type", "text/plain"}
};

var signer = new AWS4SignerForAuthorizationHeader
{
EndpointUri = uri,
HttpMethod = "GET",
Service = "s3",
Region = "us-west-2"
};

var authorization = signer.ComputeSignature(headers, "?delimiter=%2f&prefix", AWS4SignerBase.EMPTY_BODY_SHA256, AWSAccessKey, AWSSecretKey);

// place the computed signature into a formatted 'Authorization' header
// and call S3
headers.Add("Authorization", authorization);

HttpHelpers.InvokeHttpRequest(uri, "GET", headers, null);
```

I doubt something wrong I am doing while using Query-parameter because with the same program I can make GET request to download a file (passing empty query parameter in ComputeSignature method).

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Fixed this issue. I am using "delimiter "/"  in query parameter, this needs to be send as "%2F" for signing for V4 signature. Earlier i was using "%2f".